# Silverlight : Implementing Images

Tags: wpf, silverlight, image, controls

I just created a puppet in Microsoft Blend consisting of imageboxes that are displaying a dummy image(Which is a white box). In blend it shows the images but in visual studio (and when running the application) the images aren't showing.

This is a snippet of the code I am using

```
<Image Source="/Images/BodyParts/dummy.jpg" Height="10" Width="20" Stretch="Fill" OpacityMask="{x:Null}" x:Name="backFoot" Canvas.Left="41.71" Canvas.Top="147.668" />
```

[alt text http://img26.imageshack.us/img26/1401/blendvscomparewo7.jpg](http://img26.imageshack.us/img26/1401/blendvscomparewo7.jpg)

Please note that the circles you are seeing in both versions are different controls not images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure your picture *"dummy.jpg"* appears in the solution explorer within the correct folder

*example:*

[Solution Explorer http://img403.imageshack.us/img403/4976/solutiontm2.jpg](http://img403.imageshack.us/img403/4976/solutiontm2.jpg)

And if you *right click -> properties* on the image, you should see the *"Properties"* window.

Then set the *"Build Action"* to ***"Content"*** as shown below:

[Properties http://img338.imageshack.us/img338/9166/propertiesfl9.jpg](http://img338.imageshack.us/img338/9166/propertiesfl9.jpg)